# How do I create a surface graph with pyplot?

Tags: python, graph, surfaceview, surface

I have run this code as I would like to map the points in the list in a surface graph. However, while the points through Z,y,x only range from 1 to 3, the surface graph have one of the dimensions as 1 to 8. Can you help me with that?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
from plotly import __version__
print (__version__) #This is to know which version of plotly you are running ::Reference: https://www.superdatascience.com/pages/learn-plotly

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import numpy as np
z_data = np.array([
    [1,3,3],
    [1,3,3],
    [1,2,2],
    [2,2,2],
    [2,1,2],
    [2,2,2],
    [3,1,1],
    [3,1,1],
    [3,2,1],
    [3,2,2]
])
z_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

z_data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [1,3,3],
    [1,3,3],
    [1,2,2],
    [2,2,2],
    [2,1,2],
    [2,2,2],
    [3,1,1],
    [3,1,1],
    [3,2,1],
    [3,2,2]
]))

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values)])

fig.update_layout(title='3D Surface figure', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90),
                  scene=dict(
                        xaxis = dict(range=[0,9],),
                        yaxis = dict(range=[0,9],),
                        zaxis = dict(range=[0,9],)
                  ))


fig.show()
```

Figure is here:
[image]